# Problems with Spring security. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401. Spring boot 3.0.5

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

The problem is that I have a specific api that I would like to give users access to their authorization. For example ("/api/registration")

```
    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public ResponseEntity<Users> addNewUser(@RequestBody Users user, @RequestHeader Long companyId){

        Companies company = companiesService.findCompanyById(companyId);

        if (company.getId() == null){
            throw new InvalidCompany("Такой компании не существует");
        }

        user.setCompanies(company);

        if (!user.getPassword().equals(user.getPasswordConfirm())){
            throw new UserPasswordNotConfirm("Пароли не совпадают");
        }

        if (usersRepo.countByCompanies(user.getCompanies()) > company.getStaff()) {
            throw new CrowdedEmployees("Количество сотрудников превышено");
        }

        if(!userService.registrationUser(user)){
            throw new UserAlreadyExist("Пользователь уже существует");
        }

        if (accessesRepo.findByCompanyAndEmail(company, user.getEmail()) == null) {
            throw new AccessDenied("Доступ запрещен");
        }

        userService.save(user);
        accessesRepo.delete(accessesRepo.findByCompanyAndEmail(company, user.getEmail()));

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user);
    }
```

It seems nothing remarkable just user registration. Here WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final UserAuthService userAuthService;

    public WebSecurityConfig(UserAuthService userAuthService) {
        this.userAuthService = userAuthService;
    }

    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().disable()
                .csrf().disable();
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> {
                            try {
                                authz
                                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/registration").permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**" ,"/signup" ,"/").permitAll()
                                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                                        .and()
                                        .formLogin()
                                        .loginPage("/login")
                                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                                        .permitAll()
                                        .and()
                                        .rememberMe()
                                        .and()
                                        .logout()
                                        .permitAll()
                                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        }
                )
                .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity auth) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = auth.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userAuthService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

I use Spring boot version 3.0.5.
But in different browsers, then they give you to use "/api", then they don't, although I specify only one path for it.
In google chrome, I can safely use my api of any of the mappings, but let's say in Microsoft Edge I can't even use the mapping that I specified in `requestMatchers`. For example, I fail user registration.
What does Edge say to this:
[Microsoft Edge console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKWaq.png)
What does Chrome say to this:
[Google Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnBv5.png)

As I said above in Chrome, for some reason I can use any method from my api when there is none in another browser, even one that is registered as valid.

That's if that's my request for JS

```
function addUser(){
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/registration', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'companyId': document.getElementById("companySelector").value
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(
            {
                "username": document.getElementById("floatingUsername").value,
                "password" : document.getElementById("floatingPassword").value,
                "passwordConfirm" : document.getElementById("floatingPasswordConfirm").value,
                "email" : document.getElementById("floatingEmail").value
            })
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                return response.text().then(text => { throw Error(text)})
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
            window.location.replace(URL + "/login");
        })
        .catch(response => {
            let test = JSON.parse(response.message);
            let error = document.getElementById("error");

            //alert(test.message);
            console.log(`Тест: ${test.message}`);
            error.innerHTML = `<div class="form-control alert alert-danger">${test.message}</div>`
        });
}
```

I expected to get a BAD REQUEST, but in the end I get the error 401 unauthorized, also in another browser my `requestMatchers` is completely ignored

## **Edit #1**

After 1000 attempts, I finally found a solution! I just added `shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false)` into filterChain. Like this

```
                                authz
                                        .shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false)
                                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/registration").permitAll()
                                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**" ,"/signup" ,"/").permitAll()
                                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                                        .and()
                                        .formLogin()
                                        .loginPage("/login")
                                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                                        .permitAll()
                                        .and()
                                        .rememberMe()
                                        .and()
                                        .logout()
                                        .permitAll()
                                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
```

Comment: usually those type of problem is cors type issue with Edge and modern javascript Cross-Origin Resource Sharing is blocked not specific relate to ur app could be Edge enforcing some rules. You can always check by using third plugin for browser to activate cors or disabling allow you to call from Edge.